# Change KeyboardView Color Lollipin Library (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently using Lollipin library for pin protection in my app.

I am unable to find a method or xml attribute that will change the color of the buttons on the keyboard. I need them to be white.

Please check photo below.[image: Keyboard Buttons look grey]

I have tried the 'android:keyTextColor' attribute but that does not seem to change anything. Help appreciated.

Thanks

Code for keyboardView

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_gray_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pin_code_forgot_textview"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/light_gray_bar_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/light_gray_bar_margin_sides"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/light_gray_bar_margin_sides"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/light_gray_bar_margin_top"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <com.github.orangegangsters.lollipin.lib.views.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/pin_code_keyboard_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/pin_code_fingerprint_imageview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pin_code_gray_bar"
            android:keyTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:keyBackground="@color/blueAccent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Link to library: https://github.com/omadahealth/LolliPin

Comment: Try to change keyTextColor.

Comment: If this will not help you out, then add this library as a module in your project and then customize the code of CustomPinActivity. I hope you will get your desired output.